# Wordpress | password reset history

Tags: security, wordpress

In Wordpress Version-3.1.2: 
We have to a requirement to store last 13 password and don't allow user to reset a password from these recent 13 password list. To achieve it, we have found a plugin named "user-security-tools" which is having this kind of implementation for last 5. So We have modified the plugin for 13 as our requirement and it is working fine from the user profile page. But this is not working in the scenario while user is trying to reset the password using 'forget password' link, user is getting a mail containing link to reset the password. From this page user can even their current password too :(

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!
Niranjan Kumar

Comment: Given that this is a security tagged question. I'm going to point out that you are 5 versions behind and have 11 vulnerabilities http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2337/product_id-4096/version_id-112478/Wordpress-Wordpress-3.1.2.html Consider updating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this plugin. I just fix this issue and I'll still update today in WordPress.org.
And in the next major release, the number of "old password history" will be customizable.

ps.: I'll update here when I upload the new version.

UPDATE: Finish... the new version 1.1.1 fix this bug.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-security-tools/

Comment: Thanks for the resolution Erick. Yes, It is working fine. If we can make the no of password history as configurable will be great. currently it is hard coded to 5. Also On the reset password page[page by clicking on the link in the mail to reset password], If there is an error, we are displaying error message with a link 'The password is not according to the password policy Try again' and by clicking on the try again link, the form is getting opened. If possible to stay on the same page means with fields 'New password' and 'New password' with error will be good as user experience.  Thanks

Comment: Also I would recommend that the User should gets unlocked automatically after some period of time[configurable] if the user is locked by using wrong password no. of times specified. Currently Admin have to unlock the user using the link provided under the user tab in the left navigation.